# cmake error: could NOT find LibLZMA (missing: LIBLZMA_INCLUDE_DIR

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, cmake

I am trying to install [this software](https://github.com/A2-Collaboration/acqu) called acqu-root. It depends on the main software called [root](https://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/downloading-root). I managed to install the main software but having problems with the acqu-root. I get the following error.

```
[kabi@localhost build]$ cmake ..
-- *** Build Type:      Debug
-- *** Compiler Flags:  -g -O0 -Wall
-- *** Install libs to: /home/kabi/acqu-root/build/lib
-- *** Install bin to:  /home/kabi/acqu-root/build/bin
-- Looking for ROOT...
-- Looking for ROOT... - Found /home/kabi/root/bin/root
-- Looking for ROOT... - Found version is 6.03/01 
-- Configuring acqu_core...
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find LibLZMA (missing: LIBLZMA_INCLUDE_DIR LIBLZMA_LIBRARY
  LIBLZMA_HAS_AUTO_DECODER LIBLZMA_HAS_EASY_ENCODER LIBLZMA_HAS_LZMA_PRESET)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindLibLZMA.cmake:57 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  acqu_core/CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/kabi/acqu-root/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to install `lzma-devel` using `yum` (Fedora, RHEL, CentOS...), or `liblzma-dev` using `apt-get` or `aptitude` (Debian, Ubuntu...); it contains LibLZMA which the CMake configuration is looking for.

Comment: Hi, I tried installing the software on the Ubuntu, but I couldn't find the package `lzma-devel`, there is only `lzma-dev` could you instruct me how to install `lzma-devel` on Ubuntu? or how to remove `lzma-devel` references from cmake?

Comment: I was going by the Fedora tag; on Ubuntu it is just `lzma-dev` or `liblzma-dev` depending on what your source really needs.

Comment: thanks .. installing `liblzma` resolved the error. earlier I had tried installing this on fedora, now I am trying this on ubuntu.

Comment: try `xz-devel` for Centos

Answer (score 14):

Try

```
yum install xz-devel
```

on Centos to get the liblzma libraries (for Silver-searcher, for example.  Also may need  `pcre-devel` for the libpcre dependency)